# Can I transfer a PDF to iPhone then use gmail to send it by email?

Tags: iphone, email

I have a PC running Windows. It has iTunes installed. This PC does not and cannot have any Internet connectivity.

I have an iPhone 4s. (Not jail broken).

There is a PDF file on the PC. I want to transfer that file to the iPhone. Then I want to send it by email. (Preferably the gmail app).

I can use iTunes to transfer the PDF to the iPhone, but the PDF reader app has control of that file and nothing else can access it.  And it seems like the gmail app can't attach anything other than photos?

Is there a way to do this? Or should I give up with this approach?

Comment: I would definitely dump that PDF app; no app should take control of documents in that manner. As an alternative, the fee Apple app `iBooks` should let import/transfer/mail/share the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adobe Reader. You can use iTunes to transfer PDF files to and from it and  send them by email too. (Tested on an iPad; probably works the same way on an iPhone.)

Comment: This is the answer. It doesn't work for me but that's because of my email - i need to log into gmail to change settings. Thus, free and working answer = accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The commercial answer is to install a good quality PDF viewer. Even better would be to install `GoodReader` which started out as a PDF handler but can now handle a number of different file types and do any number of things with them, including email.

http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-iphone/id306277111?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4